# Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

My Ionic PWA project has camera, location cordova plugins. They are working fine. I added device motion plugin and `LinearAccelerationSensor` in my project. I referred to this [working project](https://github.com/servrox/ionic4-device-motion).

When I clone this project, it worked as expected, when I installed `device motion plugin` and copied this code in my project page

```
  if ('LinearAccelerationSensor' in window) {
      const accelerometer = new LinearAccelerationSensor();
      accelerometer.addEventListener('reading', e => { this.accelerationHandler(accelerometer, this.devicemotion6); });
      accelerometer.start();
    }
```

On `ionic cordova run browser` it started giving me error:

> ERROR in src/app/devicemotion/devicemotion.page.ts:251:33 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LinearAccelerationSensor'.

When I search the difference between 2 projects as it is working in that cloned project, after doing `ionic info`, I found below difference -

[image]

Now when I try to install `cordova platform add browser`, it says `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`

What do I do to run it with `ionic cordova run browser` without error?

Answer (score 0):

Use command

> cordova platform add browser

[Reference](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/03/04/cordova-browser-4.1.0.html)

Comment: it is saying, this is not a cordova project

Comment: do you have a www/ dir inside the project folder? if not, create an empty folder
mkdir www